# How to make a fxml file unresizable and centered

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a login and home page fxml file and I want to make them unresizable and centered in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Stage`, do:

```
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.centerOnScreen();
stage.show();
```

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#centerOnScreen%28%29, http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setResizable%28boolean%29